# I want to use double click on desktop to act as a shortcut for a few commands

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks, shortcut

Until I shifted to Mac I used to use an app called Fences in Windows to hide desktop by double clicking the desktop. I wanted a similar app to do this on the Mac OS X Mavericks but I have no clue how to do it. The closest app I made is using a global shortcut key Command+Shift+H (using the idea I found here >> https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcutDemo) to toggle between hide and show of desktop. Basically it ran the following commands and set a flag as desktop is hidden.

defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool false
killall Finder

Pressing shortcut again ran these commands
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool true
killall Finder

I want to know if this is possible to just double click on the desktop and make it happen. Pretty much like Fences. I have already tried an app called HideDesktop which works fairly simple but would love to know how to get this done. Help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Update: Found one possible solution
I found a java based solution that allowed me to make a global mouse hook. But there are certain problems, for example it doesn't detect that it's being clicked on the desktop. The code is here if anyone else comes across this problem. Other answers are very much welcome.
http://pastebin.com/uw64AjC5

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: This question should be moved to AskDifferent.

Comment: I figured there are more developers here. But anyway I will try asking there as well. Thanks

Comment: yes indeed. Here are more developers. But this has nothing to do with development. You're looking for some kind of tool or OS solution to achieve something.

Comment: I suppose it does has to do with OS internals. Anyway thanks for your suggestion to post it there

Comment: Check out **HOT Corners** in Mac(Sys Pref -> Screen Savers ->Hot Corners). You can assign a limited set of Utils(including hide desktop) to any of the four corners of your monitor. When you move your mouse to that corner that action gets triggered. Note that this cannot be customized to launch app of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for that idea but still it doesn't allow the hide desktop icons feature. I does allow me to see the desktop instantly which is cool but it still doesn't solve the primary problem